# Python VTK polydata not updating

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying use VTK to plot points, then interactively update their locations with a given set of point locations.

I can interactively use a polydata object to plot points, however they do not update when I call `self.polydata.Update()`. The points will update when I call `self.polydata.GetCellData().SetScalars(someCharArray)`

Is this a bug in VTK, or am I not updating the point coordinates correctly?

I have included an example script. If you comment out `self.polydata.GetCellData().SetScalars(someCharArray)` in sliderCallback, the plot will not update the point's coordinates when you use the slider. However they will update if you leave that line in.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.qt4.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class ViewerWithScrollBar(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewerWithScrollBar, self).__init__(parent)
        # Define the renderer and Qt window ------------------------
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()

        self.hl = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.hl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
        self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        self.frame.setLayout(self.hl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        # Point coordinate data ---------------------------------
        self.coordData = {}
        self.coordData[0] = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0]])
        self.coordData[1] = self.coordData[0] + np.array([[0.2, 0.1, -0.05], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])
        self.coordData[2] = self.coordData[1] + np.array([[0.2, 0.1, -0.05], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])

        # Define the slider bar and add it to the window ---------------
        slider = QtGui.QSlider()
        slider.setAccessibleName('Time index')
        slider.setRange(0, len(self.coordData)-1)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderCallback)

        self.hl.addWidget(slider)

        # Create the polydata object -----------------------------
        points = vtk.vtkPoints()
        points.SetNumberOfPoints(len(self.coordData[0]))
        self.polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

        for i in range(len(self.coordData[0])):
            points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[0][i])
        self.polydata.SetPoints(points)

        ptsFilter = vtk.vtkVertexGlyphFilter()
        ptsFilter.SetInputConnection(self.polydata.GetProducerPort())
        ptsMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        ptsMapper.SetInputConnection(ptsFilter.GetOutputPort())
        ptsActor = vtk.vtkActor()
        ptsActor.SetMapper(ptsMapper)
        ptsActor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(10)

        self.ren.AddActor(ptsActor)

        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()

    def sliderCallback(self):
        index = self.sender().value() # The index that the slider bar is currently on
        someCharArray = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
        points = self.polydata.GetPoints()
        for i in range(len(self.coordData[index])):
            points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[index][i])
        self.polydata.GetCellData().SetScalars(someCharArray) # For some reason the polydata won't update unless this is called.
        # self.polydata.Update()
        self.iren.Render()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = ViewerWithScrollBar()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: have you tried polydata.GetPoints().Modified() before Update ? probably setscalars is setting the modified flag to the polydata

Comment: That worked! Calling self.polydata.Modified() fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lib's advice, I modified the code. Calling self.polydata.Modified() in the sliderCallback method fixed the problem

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.qt4.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class ViewerWithScrollBar(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewerWithScrollBar, self).__init__(parent)
        # Define the renderer and Qt window ------------------------
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()

        self.hl = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.hl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
        self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        self.frame.setLayout(self.hl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        # Point coordinate data ---------------------------------
        self.coordData = {}
        self.coordData[0] = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0]])
        self.coordData[1] = self.coordData[0] + np.array([[0.2, 0.1, -0.05], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])
        self.coordData[2] = self.coordData[1] + np.array([[0.2, 0.1, -0.05], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])

        # Define the slider bar and add it to the window ---------------
        slider = QtGui.QSlider()
        slider.setAccessibleName('Time index')
        slider.setRange(0, len(self.coordData)-1)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderCallback)

        self.hl.addWidget(slider)

        # Create the polydata object -----------------------------
        points = vtk.vtkPoints()
        points.SetNumberOfPoints(len(self.coordData[0]))
        self.polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

        for i in range(len(self.coordData[0])):
            points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[0][i])
        self.polydata.SetPoints(points)

        ptsFilter = vtk.vtkVertexGlyphFilter()
        ptsFilter.SetInputData(self.polydata)
        ptsMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        ptsMapper.SetInputConnection(ptsFilter.GetOutputPort())
        ptsActor = vtk.vtkActor()
        ptsActor.SetMapper(ptsMapper)
        ptsActor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(10)

        self.ren.AddActor(ptsActor)

        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()

    def sliderCallback(self):
        index = self.sender().value() # The index that the slider bar is currently on
        points = self.polydata.GetPoints()
        for i in range(len(self.coordData[index])):
            points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[index][i])
        self.polydata.Modified()
        self.iren.Render()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = ViewerWithScrollBar()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I revised it to the version of PyQt5 and ran and tested the code above using latest vtk 8.1.0 and PyQt5 5.10.1 under Windows 10, PyCharm 2018.1 (Community Edition). Look like "points" needs to be modified instead of "self.polydata". Otherwise, it won't get the updated point shown.

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys

class ViewerWithScrollBar(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ViewerWithScrollBar, self).__init__(parent)
    # Define the renderer and Qt window ------------------------
    self.frame = Qt.QFrame()

    self.hl = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
    self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
    self.hl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

    self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
    self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
    self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
    self.ren.ResetCamera()

    self.frame.setLayout(self.hl)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

    # Point coordinate data ---------------------------------
    self.coordData = {}
    self.coordData[0] = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0]])
    self.coordData[1] = self.coordData[0] + np.array([[0.2, 0.0, -0.05], [0,2,0], [0,0,3.5]])
    self.coordData[2] = self.coordData[1] + np.array([[0.2, 10.0, -0.05], [0,5.0,0], [0,0,0]])

    # Define the slider bar and add it to the window ---------------
    slider = Qt.QSlider()
    slider.setAccessibleName('Time index')
    slider.setRange(0, len(self.coordData)-1)
    slider.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderCallback)

    self.hl.addWidget(slider)

    # Create the polydata object -----------------------------
    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    points.SetNumberOfPoints(len(self.coordData[0]))
    self.polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

    for i in range(len(self.coordData[0])):
        points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[0][i])
    self.polydata.SetPoints(points)

    self.ptsFilter = vtk.vtkVertexGlyphFilter()
    self.ptsFilter.SetInputData(self.polydata)
    ptsMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    ptsMapper.SetInputConnection(self.ptsFilter.GetOutputPort())
    self.ptsActor = vtk.vtkActor()
    self.ptsActor.SetMapper(ptsMapper)
    self.ptsActor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(10)

    self.ren.AddActor(self.ptsActor)

    self.show()
    self.iren.Initialize()
    self.iren.Start()

def sliderCallback(self):
    index = self.sender().value() # The index that the slider bar is currently on
    points = self.polydata.GetPoints()
    for i in range(len(self.coordData[index])):
        points.SetPoint(i, self.coordData[index][i])
    points.Modified() # Here you need to call Modified for points
    self.show()
    self.iren.Render()

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ViewerWithScrollBar()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```